# Prove $\dfrac{1}{2}+\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\prod_{k = 0}^{N}\text{sinc}(a_kn) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\prod_{k = 0}^{N}\text{sinc}(a_kx)\,dx$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, products

Let $N>0$ and $a_0,a_1,...,a_N$ be any  positive numbers.

How to prove that
$$\dfrac{1}{2}+\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\prod_{k = 0}^{N}\text{sinc}(a_kn) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\prod_{k = 0}^{N}\text{sinc}(a_kx)\,dx$$

Where  $\displaystyle \text{sinc}(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$, and  $\displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{N}a_k \le 2\pi$.

This is amazing...

If $a_k$ is a slowly divergent series, then  the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{N} a_k$ will exceed $2\pi$ only when N exceed
 some   $\textbf{very large} $ number $N_0$.

For instance, if $a_k=1/p_k$, sum of the reciprocals of the primes, than $N_0\approx10^{180}$

Comment: See https://www.carma.newcastle.edu.au/jon/sinc-sums.pdf